# How to include a proprietary libary into the toolchain (SDK) for an embeeded Linux generated by Yocto?

Tags: sdk, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake, toolchain

I am looking for an example which shows how to include a proprietary library into the toolchain.

Let's call the library `myLib`. For it I created a recipe `myLib.bb` and added:

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

In my "local.conf" I added:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " myLib"
```

When building the SDK by:

```
$ bitbake myTarget -c populate_sdk
```

It produces an installer for the SDK and two manifest files. `myLib` is only included in the target manifest and not on the host. How can I include `myLib` on the host system?

---

The idea is, that another person can build software on his system without the Yocto system. Only by using the toolchain he can generate binaries, which can be transferred and executed at the evalboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as your library `myLib` is installed into the image, it's supposed to be part of your generated SDK. Which you also say that it is, at least as part of the target manifest.

Ensure that you install the required header files for your library, then you should be able to cross-compile against your library.

Do you need to use `myLib` on the developers build machine? Otherwise, why do you want to have it added to the `nativesdk` part? (I.e. the host manifest). This is for applications that needs to run on the host machine, i.e. the cross-compiler, code generators etc.

Comment: I like to add it to the "nativeskd". The developer using the sdk should be able to link against the library. The idea is to have a sdk which, includes all the libs of the target system.

Comment: Well, then you don't need to add the nativesdk version at all. The nativesdk version is only needed of the developer in question needs to build something locally, for his own desktop, against your library. The target version is what is needed for cross-compiling.

Comment: @Anders - Let me see if I got your point: I have a propeitary recipe in my Yocto project, let's call it `myrecipe.bb` that has the `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"`. However, there is NO other recipe that is `DEPENDS` on it. Is it correct to say, if so, that the `BBCLASSEXTEND`  can be "left" with only the `native` part (i.e. - change myrecipes.bb to `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"`)?